# Cloned Ubuntu VMs in vSphere get same IP, despite resetting /etc/machine && /var/lib/dbus/machine-id

Tags: networking, vmware, dhcp, netplan

vSphere 7.0 + Ubuntu 18 / 20 (tried both)

I am trying the steps from this blog post:

- https://blah.cloud/kubernetes/creating-an-ubuntu-18-04-lts-cloud-image-for-cloning-on-vmware/

I also tried this blog:

- https://navneet-verma.medium.com/getting-ubuntu-cloud-init-to-work-in-vsphere-7-472b21ab9d32

Both times all my cloned Ubuntu 18 (or Ubuntu 20) VMs all get the same IP:

```
Every 30.0s: govc find / -type m -name 'k8s*' | xargs govc vm.info | grep 'Name:\|IP'                                primary: Thu Jun 16 21:31:29 2022

Name:           k8s-worker3
  IP address:   192.168.3.73
Name:           k8s-worker2
  IP address:   192.168.3.73
Name:           k8s-worker1
  IP address:   192.168.3.73
Name:           k8s-master
  IP address:   192.168.3.73
```

I'm thinking something must be wrong either with my setup or with my DHCP server itself (running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM). However, I have no DHCP reservation for this IP (192.168.3.73) at all, let alone a MAC for it.

I have tried the steps from this VMware KB: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/82229

```
echo -n > /etc/machine-id
rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
ln -s /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
```

Nothing seems to work. **Can someone please explain *exactly* how to get Cloud-Init to force the cloned Ubuntu VM to get a unique / new IP address?**

Here is my Netplan YAML file:

```
root@k8s-worker2:/etc/netplan# cat 99-netcfg-vmware.yaml
# Generated by VMWare customization engine.
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      dhcp6: yes
      dhcp6-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      nameservers:
        search:
          - myLab.local
        addresses:
          - 192.168.3.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the fix - force Netplan to use the MAC to ensure DHCP assigns a unique IP:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419321/why-are-my-cloned-linux-vms-fighting-for-the-same-ip

```
cat /etc/netplan/myNetplan.yaml

network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp-identifier: mac

# Last line was the fix
```